# OS X displays weird pattern randomly freezes and shuts off

Tags: macos, ssd, memory, gpu

I recently upgraded an early 2011 MacBook Pro, installed 2 new Kingston SSDs and two new 4 GB RAM sticks (unsure of brand, and I think what may be causing the issues, but wanted to get a second opinion).

I installed the new drives in RAID 0 for a performance boost and the 8 GB of RAM at the same time.

The problem started about a month afterwards. It wasn't until recently that it started becoming more of an issue.
The problem is that the screen gets lines "unsampled" display (I'm unsure how else to describe it) it starts beeping and shuts down.
As such this week I backed up the computer on an external drive and reformatted the drives as two separate drives (no RAID 0 anymore) thinking this could possibly be the culprit.
A couple days go by with no issue, then bam the screen comes back and shuts down not backing up any unsaved files. This time however there are no beeps, just weird screen and shuts down.

I have tried starting the computer in safeboot and starts no problem, just is unusable for my wife as the graphics runs at a lower level and graphs and data are just too slow to load. I have also tried to clear the PRAM but the issue still occurs.

Here is a picture of what happens.

[image: MacProblem]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Issues for Early 2011 Macbook Pro](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29321/display-issues-for-early-2011-macbook-pro)

Comment: Good link @klanomath - especially the possibility that there's a repair extension program. This glitch is a bit different failure than the green screen effect - that's a very specific part of the GPU whereas this can be much more RAM or CPU or GPU or even an addressing part of LVDS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are describing is a problem I had a while ago as well. For me the screen would get all messed up and depending on whether I was playing sound at that moment or not I would hear a loud screaming-like sound. Then after a couple of seconds the computer would reboot.

Replacing the ram fixed it for me.