# Some strange dynamic desktop stripes issue on Mac OS Mojave

Tags: macos

I have reboot my OS 10.14.6 (18G84) and see some strange stripes, it is not connected to Mac book screen as you can see I opened Downloads and all looks good on the second image I've attached.

What can be a problem?

when I switched to static desktop image this problem disappeared, but it's still there when I switch to dynamic desktop.

Also I've deleted cache in ~/Library/Caches on my MacBook as my Mac was freezing and I also disabled spotlight for SSD. Maybe this somehow affected on the issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29321/display-issues-for-early-2011-macbook-pro

Comment: thanks for comments! but as you there is a window over the dynamic desktop. and no issue here. I reinstalled moc os Mojave and there is no such issue.

Comment: haha) yea it's hardcore workaround. but now I know there is no graphic issue and display issue)